# C++ socket connection through proxy

Tags: c++, sockets, proxy

hello guys I ask my question,
I have this code that download a web page

```
#include <iostream>
#include <urlmon.h>
#include <string>
#pragma comment(lib,"urlmon.lib")
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string indirizzo;
    IStream * is;
    char buffer[256];
    cout<<"Insert adress of the web page: ";
    cin>>indirizzo;
    if(URLOpenBlockingStream(NULL,indirizzo.c_str(),&is,0,NULL)!=S_OK)
    {
        cerr<<"ERROR DOWNLOAD.";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"download OK"<<endl;
        system("Pause");
        ULONG readBytes;
        while(is->Read(buffer,sizeof(buffer),&readBytes)==S_OK)
        {
           cout.write(buffer,readBytes);
        }
        is->Release();
    }
    system("cls");
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

You can do this by connecting the socket via a proxy before the http request? I would like to do everything through proxy

Comment: Like most of the the HTTP APIs in Windows, `URLOpen` will use the IE proxy settings for deciding if it needs to connect over proxy.  (Control panel->Internet Options->Connections->Lan Settings).

Comment: ok, but if i wanted to do it through the socket?

Comment: What you are really trying to do?  Knowing what you are trying to do will help me and others to make suggestions for the most appropriate implementation.

Comment: BTW you are not using sockets - using sockets you would have to implement entire proxy layer yourself - probably not the best approach ;) You are using InternetExplorer API. Consider perhaps switching to WinINet, where downloading a file is only slightly more complicated, but you get much higher degree of control.

Comment: with this method is as if I visited the page? is counted as a visit to a web site ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API that you use seems to be InternetExplorer derived. It seems that you cannot use proxy's (other than system-wide) using only this API.  If that's fine with you, just set your ControlPanel proxy to desired settings and you are good to go. Browsers other than IE might even get configured so they use they own proxy settings, so you can limit the effects of system-wide settings if you need it only for your program.

If you need it stricly only for your app, or otherwise hidden/secured (users might be able to see/change IE settings) you might try to use WinINet to download your files, but that's not what you are asking. WinINet version will be lengthier and more troublesome I expect. See the [MSDN WinINet documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385483%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), specifically [InternetSetOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385114%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

**EDIT:**

I see that you will probably be able to use it to set IE settings both globally and on per-process basis. See [How to programmatically query and set proxy settings under Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/226473), and documentation for [INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385328%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) option.

To do it system-wide just use `NULL` as `hInternet` in `InternetSetOption`. To do it just for your own process, use `InternetOpen` before any other networking code, and use returned handle - it seems it should also affect dynamically loaded IE engine.

Comment: with this method is as if I visited the page? is counted as a visit to a web site?

Comment: Depends on what method server uses to count it... I suspect that anything that works for URLOpenBlockingStream will also work for WinInet. Other important thing is that if you need some login/authorization method to access file or count the visits on per-user basis, WinInet without special treatment from your code will fail. I don't know how URLOpenBlockingStream works internally, but it's likely it will use data already stored in IE, so your chances of success are greater here.

Comment: URLOpenBlockingStream does not take account of visits to the site, what could I use more than URLOpenBlockingStream?

Comment: It depends strongly on counter implementation. It might be that it only needs some cookie or other login/authentication information, but it also might be that it was specifically designed to avoid programs automating visits, in order to spin-up the counter. There is no single standard visit-count method that could be simply described here. Furthermore, it seems likely to me that what you trying to do is against policy of mentioned website - if so, don't expect my help even if you give the exact address or find out specifics of visit-counter mechanics.

Comment: and For The Love Of God, don't bump your comments, especially like this.